# Probability with 13 trees

Tags: probability

A company is planting trees and we know that 90% of the trees survive. What is the probability that from 13 trees:

1, at most $10$ survive

2, at least $10$ survive

3, exactly $10$ trees survive.

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you know about the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Comment: I just don't know how/where to start and what is the thought-process. I'd even appreciate a similar [solved] problem, because I haven't found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar problem.  Suppose we flip 10 coins.  What is the probability that at least 9 are heads?

Case 1: All 10 are heads.  This has probability $(1/2)^{10}$.

Case 2: Exactly 9 are heads.  If the first 9 are heads, and the last is tails, this has probability $(1/2)^{9}(1/2)^{1}$.  However we can choose which 9 are heads in ${10\choose 9}$ ways.  Hence the total probability is ${10 \choose 9}(1/2)^{9}(1/2)^{1}$.

Putting it together, we get $(1/2)^{10}+{10\choose 9}(1/2)^9(1/2)^{1}$.

The reason I didn't combine the $(1/2)^9(1/2)^1$ into $(1/2)^{10}$ (you can), is to distinguish the $1/2$ that comes from the probability of heads, and the $1/2$ that comes from the probability of tails.  If instead we got heads with probability $p$ and tails with probability $1-p$, the answer would be $$p^{10}+{10\choose 9}p^9(1-p)^1$$

Comment: In my case is that (the first question) : ${{13}\choose{10}}$ $(\frac{9}{10})^{10}$ $(\frac{1}{10})^{3}$ + ${{13}\choose{9}}$ $(\frac{9}{10})^{9}$ $(\frac{1}{10})^{4}$ + ... + ${{13}\choose{1}}$ $(\frac{9}{10})^{1}$ $(\frac{1}{10})^{12}$ + ${{13}\choose{0}}$ $1$ $(\frac{1}{10})^{13}$ ? And that's it? That's the solution?

Comment: That's right, you've got it.

Comment: awesome. Thanks for your time! :)